# Is there a library of OCX 7 segment and LED controls?

Tags: vb6

I was wondering if anyone knew of a Free library/OCX/ActiveX to simulate electronic devices such as 7 Segment display, LED's and switches?

I really don't care how old they are as it is just a personal, bucket list, project.

I have done Google searches, but they end up at companies websites. I thought that there were free versions around, I just can't find them.
The other alternative is to create my own, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Regards,
Craig

Comment: One option would be to use [a .NET control](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/37800/seven-segment-led-control-for-net?fid=1543113&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&fr=26) and expose it via COM interop.

Comment: I've just used a 7- or 16-segment font, such as [these](https://www.keshikan.net/fonts-e.html), and played with the size, foreground/background colors, and a box around the "display" to make fairly realistic-looking displays.

Comment: @BrianMStafford .NET controls are not automatically ActiveX/COM-compatible although it can be done https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/blob/master/OneCodeTeam/C%23%20ActiveX%20control%20(CSActiveX)/README.md.